# Get weeknumber from fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-2

I have setup fullcalendar to display weeknumbers as per the docs: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/weekNumbers#v2

I would like to get the weeknumber from fullcalendar, so I can use it in my code, because I need to display it outside of fullcalendar.

I know I can do my own calculation of week number, but I would like to get the one from fullcalendar, so I am sure, that the week number displayed in fullcalendar is always the same as the week number I display elsewhere.

Comment: As far as I know the numbers are not exposed through the API. However you could then this on its head. As described in the docs at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/weekNumberCalculation you could supply fullCalendar with your own function to calculate the week number, and also use that for your own part of the display. Then you can be sure the numbers are consistent, since they'll be calculated using the same logic

Comment: thanks. I figured it out (see my answer)

Answer (score 1):

The moment-objects seems to have a function called week(), which will return the week of the year for the moment-object: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/week/

This gets the weeknumber for the first week in a view. If the view is 'agendaWeek', then it will show the week number for the displayed week. If the view is 'month' it will get the week number for the first displayed week of the month

```
viewRender: function(view, element)
{
 alert(view.intervalStart.week());
}
```